# Error Qt 5.8 compiling on Visual Studio 2017 Community edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I installed qt 5.8 with msvc2015 https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0/
I also obviously download and installed the qt  tools on VS and everything works just fine till now. To see if everything worked I tried to open a new project with Visual C++ ---> Qt  and then selecting Qt  GUI application. When I tried to compile and run the project I get different error messages on the qalgorithm.h header saying error C3615:  a constexpr function cannot return a const value. A user here suggested me to see this link bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59575 – I tried to replace the qalgorithm.h file with the one in the link. The C3615 errors disappeared but it still doesn't compile and gives me errors LNK2038 LNK2019 LNK219 LNK1120 l. It also gives me a warning : no resources in ...\QtGuiApplication.qrc

What does that mean?

Comment: Instead of fixing this, I would recommend to use Qt 5.9 which is also LTS (long term support). In 5.9 the issues should have been fixed.

Comment: I tried to install 5.9 at first  but I encounter an error while defining the properties of QT tool on VS. If I go to to QT tools -> properties and then ADD, I choose the path on At 5.9 directory that contains the bin . VS gives me an error, It says I cannot choose MinGW because it must be Mscv . What can I do?

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing the exact configuration. I would just deinstall everything and reinstall Qt 5.9 with MingW.

Comment: I already tried to deinstall and reinstall 5.9 but that problem still remained. That's why I finally deinstalled 5.9 and installed 5.8 with Msvc and that problem disappeared. Should I try to install 5.9 with Msvc ? The problem is that I can't find it

Comment: Use the online installer tool. Select MinGW as compiler.

Answer (score 0):

When you make big changes in .h or .c files you usually get those linker problems. Sometimes, deleting the build folder and compiling again works